Compose UI Android View is not getting called sometime when scrolling multiple time
Below block for exoplayer to play videos, Sometime Android View is not getting called under BOX and complete screen is completely black due to that.
val player = remember { mutableStateOf(exoPlayer) }
    val modifierRes = remember {
        modifier
    }
    val boxModifier = remember {
        mutableStateOf(Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Black))
    }

 Box(modifier = modifierRes, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        println("LightBoxVideoComposeView========= BOX")
        AndroidView(
            modifier = boxModifier.value,
            factory = { factoryContext ->
                println("LightBoxVideoComposeView========= factory")
                PlayerView(factoryContext).also { playerView: PlayerView ->
                    playerView.useController = false
                    playerView.player = exoPlayer
                }
            }, update = { it: PlayerView ->
                // View's been inflated or state read in this block has been updated
                // Add logic here if necessary

                // As selectedItem is read here, AndroidView will recompose
                // whenever the state changes
                // Example of Compose -> View communication
                println("LightBoxVideoComposeView========= Update")
                it.useController = false
                it.player = player.value
            }
        )
    }

LightBoxVideoComposeView========= Initialise  
LightBoxVideoComposeView========= LightBoxVideoContent Loading Start Modifier  LightBoxVideoComposeView========= BOX 
Some code added after see suggestion that could be issue of recomposition but still is happening.
As beter see in log till log Box has called but after that "factory" and "update" log not being printed.
Try to fix this issue to every time Android view should load with exoPlayer View
